# sql select between spaces

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a land description stored as follows:

```
NW 1/4 6 7 5 E
NW 1/4 17 7 5 E
```

I need to output it as follows:

```
NW6-7-5E
NW17-7-5E
```

Because the third grouping of characters can be either 1 or 2 characters I can't use LEN for the selection.  I've managed to get this far:

```
Select Left(quartersection,2)+SUBSTRING(quartersection,8,CHARINDEX(' ',quartersection)-1)+'-'
```

Where I'm stuck is selecting the items between the 3rd and 4th space and the 4th and 5th space.  Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: will this be fixed format always? what is dynamic here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. **[`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)**, **[`Right`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177532.aspx)**, **[`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177601.aspx)** and **[`Len`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)**  string functions should help you

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50)='NW 1/4 17 7 5 E ' --NW 1/4 6 7 5 E

SELECT Replace(Replace(LEFT(@a, Len(@a)-3), ' 1/4 ', ''), ' ', '-')
       + Replace(RIGHT(@a, 4), ' ', '')
```

**OUTPUT** : `NW17-7-5E`

Answer (score 1):

With Replace,Stuff and LEN functions:

```
create table #temp(quartersection varchar(20)) 

insert into #temp values('NW 1/4 17 7 5 E ')
insert into #temp values('NW 1/4 2 7 6 E ')

select * from #temp

SELECT Replace(Stuff(Replace(Replace(Rtrim(quartersection), '1/4', ''), '  ', ''), Len(Replace(Replace(Rtrim(quartersection), '1/4', ''), '  ', '')) - 1, 1, ''), ' ', '-')
FROM   #temp
```

[image]